# Make an MS Access Report label visible based on data in the report's record source query

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access, I have a report based on a query that presents a summary of a medical checkup. I would like labels for each test to be visible ONLY when those tests were performed. For example, if Glucose was performed on a patient, then the label "lblGlucose" should appear in the report, next to the result. The results currently are present in the report, the problem is when a test is not performed the label is always present. This gives the patient a feeling that the testing was not performed correctly.

To hide the labels I have tried the following approaches:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

'1st approach: Lookup column [GLUCOSE] from query qrySummary if not null then set visible property of label lblGLUCOSE to True, else set property to False

IIF(IsNotNull(DLookup("[GLUCOSE]", "qrySummary")),Me!lblGLUCOSE.Visible = True,Me!lblGLUCOSE.Visible = False)
    
'2nd approach: If value of field [GLUCOSE_RSLT] from table tblResults make textbox txtGlucose visible. FYI: Table tblResults is the table that holds all the results of all the test performed. The query qrySummary derives from this table.

Me!txtGlucose.Visible = Not IsNull([tblResults]![GLUCOSE_RSLT])

'3rd approach: Count column [GLUCOSE], from query qrySummary and if greater than 0 then label lblBHClbl visible

End Sub
```

I'm still coding the 3rd approach but I'm pretty much running out of ideas and getting nowhere. For first two approaches I get field or expression not found. I don't need for all approaches to work, just one, -in fact, I'm open to other ideas on how I can accomplish the above task.

Any help would be ENORMOUSLY appreciated! Thanks a million!
I'm sharing my DB structure for better understanding
[image: db structure]

The SQL statement for the summary report is:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frmIngresoEmpleados]![IDChequeo] Long;
SELECT TblClienteCorp.NombreEmpresa, TblClienteCorp.Direccion, tblChequeo.IDChequeo, tblChequeo.FechaMuestreo, tblChequeo.ChequeoPeriodico, qryCountGenero.*, tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.Genero, tblResultados.Aud_RSLT, tblResultados.Otos_RSLT, tblResultados.AV_RSLT, tblResultados.EKG_RSLT, tblResultados.FR_RSLT, tblResultados.TGP_RSLT, tblResultados.TGO_RSLT, tblResultados.CS_RSLT, tblResultados.ESP_RSLT, tblResultados.PB_RSLT, tblResultados.BHC_RSLT, tblResultados.Plaquetas_RSLT, tblResultados.EGO_RSLT, tblResultados.EGH_RSLT, tblResultados.VDRL_RSLT, tblResultados.Gluc_RSLT, tblResultados.Col_RSLT, tblResultados.EFEC_RSLT, tblResultados.PL_RSLT, tblResultados.Derm_RSLT, tblResultados.Isop_RSLT, tblResultados.BAAR_RSLT, tblResultados.ExFarin_RSLT, tblResultados.Lep_RSLT, tblResultados.Copro_RSLT, tblResultados.Osteo_RSLT, tblResultados.RX_RSLT, tblResultados.US_RSLT
FROM TblClienteCorp INNER JOIN ((tblChequeo INNER JOIN (tblEmpleadosClienteCorp INNER JOIN qryCountGenero ON tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDEmpleado = qryCountGenero.IDEmpleado) ON tblChequeo.IDChequeo = tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDChequeo) INNER JOIN tblResultados ON tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDEmpleado = tblResultados.IDEmpleados) ON TblClienteCorp.IDClienteCorp = tblChequeo.IDClienteCorp
WHERE (((tblChequeo.IDChequeo)=[Forms]![frmIngresoEmpleados]![IDChequeo]));
```

Within the report that is one query per test, which is:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frmIngresoEmpleados]![IDChequeo] Long;
SELECT Count(tblResultados.IDEmpleados) AS CuentaDeIDEmpleados, tblResultados.Gluc_RSLT, tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDChequeo
FROM tblEmpleadosClienteCorp INNER JOIN tblResultados ON tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDEmpleado = tblResultados.IDEmpleados
GROUP BY tblResultados.Gluc_RSLT, tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDChequeo
HAVING (((tblResultados.Gluc_RSLT)="P") AND ((tblEmpleadosClienteCorp.IDChequeo)=[Forms]![frmIngresoEmpleados]![IDChequeo]));
```

Comment: What is the data structure (show sample data as text table)? How is data loaded to report (show SQL)? Why is there a label for each test? Edit your question.

Comment: Use dot instead of bang (!) when referencing controls: `Me.lblGlucose.Visible`. There is no IsNotNull function, use: `IIf(IsNull(...), this if true, this if false)` or `Nz(DLookup(), "something")`.

Comment: Why would there be a label if there is no field to associate with? Why are you using DLookup() instead of just referencing field?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and suggestions. To answer your questions:

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and suggestions. To answer your questions: How is data loaded to report (show SQL)? There's a form that gathers data and feeds it to the results table (tblResults). Why is there a label for each test? There's a label for each test because I'm using a count query which only returns the quantity of test per test performed in a medical checkup, for example 100 Glucose tests for a corporate client that employs 100 people. I'm opened to suggestions on to how I can improve my current way of structuring the data, designing and coding. Thanks so much for your feedback!

Comment: That comment doesn't really clarify and doesn't alter my answer. The image is barely comprehensible to me because I speak only English. By "count query" do you mean a simple GROUP BY aggregate or a CROSSTAB? Again, post the report RecordSource SQL. How many possible tests? Would be nice to have sample data relevant to issue as text table(s). Edit question.

Comment: Hi again June7! Thanks for your continuous support. I edited the question to add the main SQL statements that calls the data from the tables and an additional SQL statement that counts the quantity of Glucose test that were performed (I have an SQL statement per test -not efficient at all, sorry...)

Comment: A query for each test?!?! One query should suffice. This has gotten way too complicated and confusing for this platform. Consider posting to a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis. Did you try suggestions in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If qrySummary has multiple patient records, need WHERE CONDITION criteria:
`Me.lblGlucose.Visible = Not IsNull(DLookup("[GLUCOSE]", "qrySummary", "PatientID=" & Me!PatientID))`

However, VBA is not necessary. Calculate in textbox (or in query and bind textbox to calculated field) and set control with transparent BorderStyle. Options:

1. show "None" text when no data:

   `=Nz(DLookup("[GLUCOSE]", "qrySummary", "PatientID=" & Me!PatientID), "None")`.
2. instead of label, use a textbox with expression:

   `=IIf(IsNull(DLookup("[GLUCOSE]", "qrySummary", "PatientID=" & Me!PatientID)), "", "Glucose")`

Comment: Hi again June7!!! Thanks a million for all your feedback and time invested in going over my case. I have tried both proposed solutions and both work wonderfully! Thanks again!

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.

Comment: Hi again! New here, where's the "accept answer" option?

Comment: Click the check mark symbol at left side of answer.